# My text is getting cut at the edge while trying to display it in a listview

Tags: android

[image]When I try to display `TextView` inside my `Listview`. The text that are long in length or width are getting cut at the edge. So how do I prevent it. Please help like some parts of the textviews don't show and are cut off by the edge of the screen.
I have already tried the android's `ellipsize attribute`, but not working and also the `maxlines attribute` trying to show the edges which are getting cut to be shown on the next line

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="OpenSans-Regular">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Brand: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

             <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/brand"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                 android:ellipsize="marquee" />


       </TableRow>
```

Comment: Add your code, screenshot, error log, ... Add more information to your question if you want someone to answer.

Comment: try doing setSingleLine(false).. And ListItems layout-params to WRAP_CONTENT.

Comment: Have your tried Horizontal Scroll view for the text view inside list view so that you can scroll horizontally when text is more in length

Comment: Post your code please where you are adding the text.

Comment: that would add to the annoyance of the user using the app

Comment: zoya. I have posted my xml code and the ouput image

Comment: @user3928711 post full `xml` and desired `screenshot` nd don't post it as an answer use `edit` option in ur question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  

</ScrollView>
```

Hope it help.

If still getting problem please comment below.

Thanks :)

Comment: Try adding scroll view to only that textview not to the whole layout